# how to grep each non-unique combination from two colums

Tags: bash, awk, count, grep

I have a tsv file with two columns.

```
01.01.1990 name1
01.01.1990 name1
01.01.1990 name2
02.01.1990 name1
02.01.1990 name2
```

I would like to count the occurrence of each name in each day and get something like this:

```
01.01.1990 name1 2
01.01.1990 name2 1
02.01.1990 name1 1
02.01.1990 name2 1
```

I've just used grep  | , grep  | ...

Comment: If the file is sorted already, `uniq -c file` should do the trick. Otherwise, use `sort file | uniq -c`

Comment: Did you say `non-unique combination from two colums` instead of just `line` because your real file has more than 2 columns but you only want to test 2 of them? If so - add more columns in the appropriate locations to your sample input/output so we can see what you really want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
awk '{arr[$0]++}END{for(i in arr) print i, arr[i]}' file
01.01.1990 name1 2
02.01.1990 name1 1
01.01.1990 name2 1
02.01.1990 name2 1
```